# How to create object that would be an instance of HasherInterface?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to extend auth provided by Laravel and stuck at `EloquentUserProvider` which requires `HasherInterface` in constructor. How i can create this object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hasher is bound to the IoC container as `hash`, and can be resolved from the container using a couple of different methods. The method you use usually depends on where exactly you're extending the authentication layer.

To resolve the hasher from the container:

```
$hasher = App::make('hash');

$hasher = $app['hash'];
```

When extending auth the callback you supply should receive the application container as the first parameter. You can access the hasher using the second method described above.

```
Auth::extend('custom', function($app)
{
    $hasher = $app['hash'];

    return YourAuthProvider($hasher);
});
```